# hello, what's the "CDATA" for php?

Tags: php, string, cdata

When I Put html tag into html file, I can warp them by `CDATA`. I want to display `<?php ... ?>` tag as content in php file too.

`CDATA` rule is run on client side, can't help for PHP. Now I am using `&lt;` and `&gt;` to replace the `<` and `>`.

Is there any better idea to show the php code?

Comment: cant you just do something like: `<?php echo '<?php'; ?>`

Comment: You seem to be attached to this idea of "CDATA". Perhaps you should just ask what you're trying to ask instead.

Answer (score 1):

Store whatever data you wish to be displayed as a string variable in PHP:

```
$x = "<?php my awesome PHP code lies here ?>";
```

and use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function to [output the data](http://codepad.org/dY89tF3g):

```
echo htmlentities( $x );
```